# Why does restricting the domain not eliminate this solution?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Beside this specific problem I'm wondering if there's a more explicit way that I can understand when Solve and Reduce will find solutions. I find myself repeatedly getting stuck where I'll get positive and negative solutions for $x$ from Solve, add $x>0$ to the equations it's solving, and then get no solutions. Often specifying `PositiveReals` in `Solve` will return no solutions, even if there were no negative or nonreal solutions to begin with. I'm learning a lot by experimentation, but I don't feel like I'm coming to understand how these tools work.

I know part of the issue is that I've been unaware of how many assumptions I make when I work out problems by hand, but are there other factors that I can learn about?

First a CWE; I've removed units here for clarity and confirmed the behavior is the same.

```
g = 9.81; m = 2; ρ = 2; v0 = 6;

Solve[{
    Fw == m g,
    Fw Sin[Θ] == m an,
    an == v^2/ρ,
    -ρ g Sin[Θ] == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2)
    }, {Θ, v, Fw, an}]]
```

yields
$$\{\{\theta \to 0.658108,v\to -3.4641,\text{Fw}\to 19.62,\text{an}\to 6.\},\\\{\theta \to 0.658108,v\to 3.4641,\text{Fw}\to 19.62,\text{an}\to 6.\}\}$$
where the $v<0$ case should be eliminated.

Note that in each of these examples I've tried `Solve`, `Reduce`, `Simplify`, `FullSimplify`, `v>0`, and `v ∈ PositiveReals`

I've tried with the first line as

```
Assuming[v > 0, Simplify@Solve[{
```

which warned me about inverse functions, so I used Reduce and saw those extra solutions on the domain of $\sin^{-1}$. So I added a constraint

```
Assuming[{v > 0, 0 <= Θ < 2 π}, Simplify@Reduce[{
```

and I tried using without `Assuming`

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[{
   ...
   }, {Θ, v, Fw, an}], {v ∈ PositiveReals, 0 <= Θ < 2 π}]
```

Finally I connected the dots when adding $v>0$ as part of the system gave

$$\left\{\left\{\theta \to \text{ConditionalExpression}[6.28319 c_1+0.658108,c_1\in \mathbb{Z}],\\v\to \text{ConditionalExpression}\left[3.4641 \left(1\text{m}/\text{s}\right),c_1\in \mathbb{Z}\right]\right.\right.$$

so I solved the problem by including both $v>0$ and $0\leq\theta<\pi$ in the system, and discovered there were more solutions than I thought

$$\left\{\left\{\theta \to 0.658108,v\to 3.4641\text{m}/\text{s},\text{Fw}\to 19.62\text{N},\text{an}\to 6.\text{m}/\text{s}^2\right\},\\\left\{\theta \to 2.48349,v\to 3.4641\text{m}/\text{s},\text{Fw}\to 19.62\text{N},\text{an}\to 6.\text{m}/\text{s}^2\right\}\right\}$$

but then why didn't I get the $\theta \to 2.48349$ solution the first time, before adding any constraints? And why did none of the other methods eliminate the negative solution?

<strike>Finally, solving it this way (also with `NSolve`) warned that it wasn't able to solve with inexact coefficients. How can I give it exact values instead of silencing it?</strike>

**Edit:** The solution to the inexact coefficients warning is to change the first line with `g=Rationalize[9.81];`

It's clear I don't understand these tools well enough to get more than the very basics out of them. What is it that I don't know I don't know here?

Comment: "why didn't I get the θ→2.48349 solution the first time, before adding any constraints?" Well, `Solve` EXPLICITLY warned you that "Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found". So you would attempt `Reduce` as the warning says. `Reduce` would tell you that "Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients". So then you would rationalize your `g` (e.g. `g = 981/100`) and `Reduce` would work without a hitch. Going back to `Solve` with the rationalized system would show four solutions now, **just by following the instructions in the warnings**.

Comment: If you then add the constraint that `v >=0` to that last `Solve` system, it reduced the number of solutions to two, including periodic conditions. You could then set C[1] to e.g. zero to get an instance of the solution (e.g. `Solve[...]  /. C[1] -> 0`).

Comment: FWIW: the error messages are not always instructive, but this is one of those cases where you really should have paid attention to them.

Comment: @MarcoB I see your point, but actually in my original problem, which is exactly as written here but with units, Solve does *not* warn that inverse functions are being used. It returns the two solutions I listed first with no other message.

Comment: I did find that adding the inequalities to the Solve equations fixed it, and I found that by following the error messages. My confusion is that another issue I had was resolved by adding a constraint in Simplify, but here that has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the equations, include the inequalities as constraints

```
g = 9.81; m = 2; ρ = 2; v0 = 6;

sol = Solve[{Fw == m g, Fw Sin[Θ] == m an, an == v^2/ρ,
    -ρ g Sin[Θ] == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2),
    v > 0, 0 <= Θ < 2 Pi}, {Θ, v, Fw, an}] // 
  Quiet

(* {{Θ -> 0.658108, v -> 3.4641, Fw -> 19.62, 
  an -> 6.}, {Θ -> 2.48349, v -> 3.4641, Fw -> 19.62, an -> 6.}} *)

sol /. x_Real :> RootApproximant[x]

(* {{Θ -> π - ArcSin[200/327], v -> 2 Sqrt[3], Fw -> 981/50, 
  an -> 6}, {Θ -> ArcSin[200/327], v -> 2 Sqrt[3], Fw -> 981/50,
   an -> 6}} *)
```

Or

```
sol = Solve[{Fw == m g, Fw Sin[Θ] == m an, an == v^2/ρ,
    -ρ g Sin[Θ] == 1/2 (v^2 - v0^2),
    v > 0, 0 <= Θ < 2 Pi} // Rationalize, {Θ, v, 
   Fw, an}]

(* {{Θ -> π - ArcSin[200/327], v -> 2 Sqrt[3], Fw -> 981/50, 
  an -> 6}, {Θ -> ArcSin[200/327], v -> 2 Sqrt[3], Fw -> 981/50,
   an -> 6}} *)
```

Comment: I didn't know I can just rationalize the whole equation like that, thanks! That has fixed a bunch of instances where I was using Quiet.